# What are the arguments for and against using the Lightning Network with Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network

In addition to the question in the title, when will Lightning Network go online, or, if there isn't a proposed date yet, what is a ballpark indication of when it might go online?

Answer (score 1):

pros:

- Lower Transactions Fees
- More Transactions per second / block possible
- micropayments possible
- payments are more private than on bitcoin

cons:

- funds are on a hot wallet
- (at least currently) node needs to be online all the time
- still somewhat buggy
- (at least currently) only small amounts can be routed